# Incoming email to PHP: need to write attachments to web directory

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP script that is accepting all emails (wildcard) to my domain, and inserting the data into MySQL.

The beginning of the script has this line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

It then looks like a regular PHP script. The part that writes the attachments to disk seems to work but the permissions on the new folders where they're stored were created by the 'nobody' user.

How can I edit permissions so that after these files are written to disk, they can be accessed by the webserver/webserver user?

Thanks for the help!

(Fedora 14 Linux server, Postfix)

Comment: I would love to see the script after `#!/usr/bin/php -q`... How do you read attachments from e-mails and save them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preform your file system operations by FTP so you will have the same permissions as your user.
its better then give all the PHP users on server access to your files.
http://php.net/ftp

Comment: I have the base64 encoded file attachment data that gets parsed from the email headers in a string. Can I use PHP's FTP functions to upload a file if I don't actually have a source file to transfer?

Comment: Thanks, I used the FTP functions and got around it!

Answer (score 0):

What user is PHP running as? PHP does have a [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function, but you can't elevate privileges higher than what the user PHP is running as.

If that doesn't do the trick, could you chown the attachment directory to be owned by whatever user PHP is running as?

Comment: PHP is running as 'nobody' and I don't think its using Apache at all. I tried adding PHP ('nobody') to the group that has permission to write and read from that folder but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

> chown -R apache:apache directory_name

This is because PHP runs as the web server user (I believe this is **apache** on Fedora). Otherwise, if you are using a different web server, then change the ownership of the files to that web server's user (you are sure to find this in the server's configuration files somewhere).

Comment: I don't think Apache is being used to run this script... All emails to my domain come into my server as usual, which invokes the PHP script. All the data is recorded to MySQL and the files are written to a directory that the webserver (nginx for static files) can begin serving files from, except that the server doesn't have permission.

Comment: In that case, you will need to do this:

chown -R nginx:nginx directory_name

Answer (score 0):

You need `sticky bits` on the file server level.

[setting the sui/sgid bits](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_setting_suid_sgid_bits)